# Using Regular expression on SQL Server instead of of combining two LIKE statements

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, union, sql-like

Is there a way I can use regular expression to avoid a UNION of two LIKE statements?
for eg: i have the following

```
SELECT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE NAME LIKE 'Adam%'
UNION
SELECT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE NAME LIKE 'Bob%'
```

I don't want to use a UNION and combine the two select statements into one using regular expression. Please help with regex solution or an alternate solution. thanks in advance

Comment: Oops, I forogt to mention. OR clause is not allowed in this question which was an interview questin. sorry about not mentioning it before

Comment: No way a regular expression is going to be more efficient than a union or an or.   The is a weak question.

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE NAME LIKE 'Bob%' OR NAME LIKE 'Adam%'
```

should work just fine.

Comment: Oops, I forogt to mention. OR clause is not allowed in this question which was an interview questin. sorry about not mentioning it before. is there a solution with REGEX ?

Comment: It would just be an OR in the regex and would need to do CLR integration to get regex.

Comment: Yeah, it being an interview question was kind of important. heh.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you can't use "OR", use "And" instead:

Condition1 OR Condition <=> NOT( NOT(Condition1) AND NOT(Condition2) )